# Today extension doesn't appear on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, today-extension, ios8-today-widget

Today extension doesn't appear on simulator. After selecting the extension target when i ran the project ,it showed - 'Running com.springboard.apple on iPhone 7' on Xcode but widget screen didn't appear. Just the default simulator appeared and then nothing happened.Ran this on xCode 8.3 with deployment target 8.0 for all targets. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: A today extension widget doesn't just "appear". You have to enable it. Think about what you'd have to do on your phone for someone else's extension. That is what you must do on the simulator.

Comment: The application is not being showing in 'Add widgets' screen. I first tried this with a new project and everything worked fine there. Then i was trying to integrate this with my existing project and it's not working there.

Comment: Do you happen to call `setHasContent(_:forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier:)` of [NCWidgetController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter/ncwidgetcontroller/1456693-sethascontent) and pass `false` to the first parameter?